# How do I call a method every x seconds?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I have a NSWindow that I'm putting into fullscreen mode. I would like to be able to hide the mouse when its not in use (say 15 seconds after it was last used). I have my application delegate as follows:

MyMediaRoomAppDelegate.h:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface MyMediaRoomAppDelegate : NSResponder <NSApplicationDelegate> {
    NSWindow *window;
    NSDate *lastMouseMove;
}

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *lastMouseMove;

@end
```

MyMediaRoomAppDelegate.m:

```
#import "MyMediaRoomAppDelegate.h"

@implementation MyMediaRoomAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize lastMouseMove;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // The application has just finished lanching

    // Grab the screen size
    NSRect screenRect;
    screenRect = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

    // Setup the window - full screen
    [[self window] setLevel:NSMainMenuWindowLevel+1];
    [[self window] setStyleMask:NSBorderlessWindowMask];
    [[self window] setOpaque:YES];
    [[self window] setBackgroundColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
    [[self window] setFrame:screenRect display:YES animate:NO];

    // Setup the mouse
    [[self window] setAcceptsMouseMovedEvents:YES];
    [[self window] makeFirstResponder:self];
    [NSCursor hide];
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)mouseMoved:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [NSCursor unhide];
    [self setLastMouseMove: [NSDate date]];
}

@end
```

What I'm not sure about is how to re-hide the cursor after 15 seconds. The thing is I need to check setLastMouseMove, every second or so, not just call `[NSCursor hide]` after 15 seconds is up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html). You can specify it to be repeating at creation time.